# How to change input value based on variable?

Tags: php

Im trying to change input value based on variable but code is not working:

```
<form action="czekboks.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="przycisk" <?php echo 'value="$keepchecked"'?>>
</form>
```

I tried also this but the same result:

```
<form action="czekboks.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="przycisk" <?php echo ($keepchecked == "OBEJRZANE") ? 'value="OBEJRZANE"' : '';?>>
</form>
```

Comment: You should debug what `$keepchecked` value is. I think you're not setting that variable or setting it to other value than `OBEJRZANE`. You should provide more info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<form action="czekboks.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk" <?= ($keepchecked == "OBEJRZANE") ? 'value="OBEJRZANE"' : '';?>>
</form>
```

or this:

```
<form action="czekboks.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk" value="<?= $keepchecked; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="czekboks.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk" value="<?php echo $keepchecked;?>">
</form>
```